# Use code format inside mermaid to display R code

Tags: quarto, mermaid

I would like to display R code similar to markdown code, e.g. `r_code`. Is this possible with mermaid?

**MWE**:

````
---
format: html
---
  
```{mermaid}
%%{init: {'themeVariables': { 'edgeLabelBackground': 'white'}}}%%

flowchart TD
  X1(First) --> X2(own_r_function)
```
````

My attempt:

````
---
format: html
---
  
```{mermaid}
%%{init: {'themeVariables': { 'edgeLabelBackground': 'white'}}}%%

flowchart TD
  X1(First) --> X2(`own_r_function`)
```
````

[image]

Comment: by `own_r_function`, do you intend to show some computed result generated from an r function?

Comment: no just the format. But it would also be amazing if it could be linked, e.g. [`own_r_function`](link.html)

Comment: What does your `own_r_function` look like?

Comment: It does not matter, it could also be dplyr or anything, I just want to have the code styling like for instance here: `dplyr` which is done by using backticks in markdown. I am searching for a way to do the same thing in mermaid. Hope that clarifies it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach could be using a [css class](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html?id=flowcharts-basic-syntax#css-classes) to mimic the code format style of Quarto for text wrapped within `span` tag. And note that, `code` tag also works.

````
---
format: html
---

```{=html}

<style>

.codeStyle span:not(.nodeLabel) {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #9753b8 !important;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

</style>
```


```{mermaid}
%%{init: {'themeVariables': { 'edgeLabelBackground': 'white'}}}%%

flowchart TD
  X1(First) --> X2(This is some text <span>own_r_function</span> in custom styled code format using span tag)
  class X2 codeStyle
  X2 --> X3(This is some text <code>own_r_function</code> in custom styled code format using code tag)
```
````

---

[image: code text format in mermaid nodes]

---